# fabric-samples:balance-transfer example - v1.1.0 - Missing instructions?

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric

fabric-samples:balance-transfer example - v1.1.0 - on a customized network with cryptogen generated crypto - fabric-client-kv* contents are failing to be created. Missing instructions? Please provide what needs to be done for creating these folders and contents in root directory of sample and in /tmp directory for wallet setup.

1. Created a customized network
2. Generated cryptogen content for the customized network
3. Brought of the network and verified it to be correctly running
4. Adapted the runApps.sh and testAPIs.sh scripts to use customized network with its crypto
5. User enroll and registration process failed due to missing fabric-client-kv* contents
6. This is not an issue when sample itself is run. The fabric-client-kv* contents are generated or re-generated
7. What is missing and what needs to be done to succeed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We invite you to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Could you please reformat your question be more clear on what you expect, what you tried and what you are getting wrong? For this, you may provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you regenerate the certificates same should be updated in docker-compose and network-config. If your adding a new organization to the network, Need to create a network connection profile configuration which will have the setting for keyValueStore and cryptoStore. In the balance transfer example crypto materials are stored in tmp folder, In this case, if you restart the system you will lose those materials, You can change these configurations on org*.yaml.